# Deploy 3 Tier MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have created a Web Application in MVC 3 with razor. My solution structure is as follows:

```
A) Web Tier - Comprises of MVC
B) Business Layer
C) Data Tier
```

I am required to deploy the three layers separately on 3 servers, on IIS. 
Can anyone advise how to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: But is your Business Layer designed to be deployed on a seperate physical machine, does it have services? Remoting? There are alot of preconditions before you are able to deploy to seperate physical tiers.. You should provide more details about the architecture..

Comment: @Anas Karkoukli: I have just come to know about the deployment issue. While coding we have not considered Remoting or services.

Comment: @Anas Karkoukli: Kindly provide further suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are concerned about where to deploy your edmx file, I will just elaborate on the business layer.

First I would reiterate the distinction between layer and tier. You mention a seperate physical server for your business logic, **therefore my answer will assume a physically separate business tier**. And will henceforth refer to as a tier.

The EDMX file, although coupled to your database schema, is a business tier artifact. IT will have to be on the same physical location (in your case) as your other business classes (entities, data access plumbing, etc...)

In your situation, your biggest hurdle is the B component. Deploying A and C (a web application and a database respectively) onto separate physical tiers is not particularly difficult.

You will definitely need to build a WCF service Facade on top of your business logic classes to expose their functionality to the MVC website that resides on a different server. There are ample articles out there elaborating on the Facade pattern, but this is a direct approach that involves minimal changes in your architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking into Facade Pattern for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

B needs to be wrapped by a webservice which A calls.

C is the database server? Simply install it on a seperate server.

Comment: Thanks for advise. "C" is where I have put in my EDMX file( I am using Entity framework 4). Should I deploy B & C together ?

Comment: yes. Then B and C is two layers in the second tier. The actual database SqlServer is the third tier.

Comment: I am using Unity framework for invoking methods in Business layer. This is done through Inversion of Control. How  do I wrap the business tier in WCF service & then call the methods of Business tier from Web Tier ?

Comment: You can use a proxy class which implement the business layer interfaces. But that's another question (i.e create a new question here at SO and ask how you can solve that).

Answer (score 1):

A) This goes into an ASP.NET MVC application on ServerA

B) This goes into a WCF service hosted on ServerB that your ASP.NET MVC application will consume

C) This is the SQL Server or whatever you are using and which will be requested by the web service and this goes on ServerC

Comment: Thanks for advise. "C" is where I have put in my EDMX file( I am using Entity framework 4). Should I deploy B & C together ?

Comment: @Vipul, I think you misunderstand something. There are physical boundaries (tiers) and logical boundaries (layers). So it seems that you are talking about logical boundaries here. Not physical even if in your question you mention different servers. You could define 3 different logical boundaries in your application which would be a data access layer, a business layer and UI. All those will be deployed on a single server inside a single ASP.NET MVC application. EDMX files will be part of the data access layer.

Comment: Thanks :).  I understand your point. I am required to deploy data access layer, a business layer and UI, all on 3 different machines. Kindly advise.

Comment: @Vipul, then see my answer: UI is the ASP.NET MVC application which goes into ServerA, business layer and data access layer could be encapsulated inside a WCF service which you deploy on ServerB and finally you have a database server on ServerC.